# xml to dataframe with correct column names

Tags: r, xml

I'm trying to import an XML file with one set of responses into R. Here's a [link to a version with dummy data](https://duke.box.com/s/87k0wfgesuyzfzy3uyx448w8dyyybe9h) that shows the structure of the file.

I've tried to wrangle this into a dataframe with the `XML` package as follows:

```
library(XML)
file <- "test.xml"
data <- xmlParse(file)
xml_data <- xmlToList(data)
df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(xml_data), nrow=1, byrow=T))
```

This gives me 482 columns.

Next I try to extract the column names unsuccessfully.

```
n <- NULL
for (i in 1:length(xml_data)) {
  if (length(xml_data[[i]])==1) {
    n <- c(n, names(xml_data[i]))
  }
  if (length(xml_data[[i]])>1) {
    n <- c(n, names(xml_data[[i]]))
  }
}
```

This only gives a vector of length 290, so I'm short a bunch of column names.

Any ideas on where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your reduced list is the not parsing all of the children nodes in xml document.
Since you have all ready parsed the document into xml_data, try extracting the names from that list:

```
n<-names(unlist(xml_data))
```

This will provide the list of the 482 names which you requested.

**Edit:**
To provide the list of just the node names and values, I used the xml2 package to recursively search the XML document and extract the requested information.  This solution also has the benefit of extracting the value from *all* of the nodes whether, there is information present or not.  This sample data has 754 elements, at a max of 3 levels deep:

```
library(xml2)
filename <- "C:\\Users\\SO\\Downloads\\test.xml"
df<-data.frame()
findchildren<-function(nodes, df){
  numchild<-sapply(nodes, function(x){length(xml_children(x))})
  xmlname<-xml_name(nodes[numchild==0])
  xmlvalue<-xml_text(nodes[numchild==0])
  xmlpath<-sapply(nodes[numchild==0], function(x) {toString(rev(xml_name(xml_parents(x))))})
  dftemp<-data.frame(xmlname, xmlvalue, xmlpath)
  df<-rbind(df, dftemp)
  print(dim(df))
  if (sum(numchild)>0){
    findchildren(xml_children(nodes[numchild>0]), df) }
  else{ return(df)}
}

file<-read_xml(filename)
df<-findchildren(xml_children(file), df)
```

The final dataframe 'df' has 3 columns: element name, element value and a string with parent node names.  Dataframe order is by node level, thus the elements at the top nodes are at the top of the dataframe and the elements on the third level is at the bottom.

Comment: this is helpful. the names are not quite right in that they contain `something.varname` and `something.something.varname`. I just need to keep everything after the last period.

Comment: `sub('.*\\.', '', names(unlist(xml_data)))` gets close, except that I have a few variables names that are like `varname.1`, which get cut to `1`, etc.